# Como mostrar imagenes en una secuencia en python

Tags: python, lista, tkinter, imagen

tengo una lista de imagenes

y quiero que se muestren de una en una y en orden y que cada vez que se inicie el programa se muestre la siguiente

Ejemplo:

Inicia el programa 1 vez

Img1

Inicia el programa 2 vez

Img2...

y así

he intentado con el for loop y me muestra es la posición en la lista

[CORRECCION DESPUES DE LOS COMENTARIOS]

volví a revisar el loop la entrada es esta:

```
def imgor():
          for imagen in Imagenes:
               imagen
               print imagen
     Imagenfin=imgor()
     lbl=Label(root,image=imgor()).place(x=00,y=00)
```

y la salida es esta:

```
    >>> pyimage1
pyimage2
pyimage3
pyimage4
pyimage5
pyimage7
pyimage8
pyimage9
pyimage10
pyimage1
pyimage2
pyimage3
pyimage4
pyimage5
pyimage7
pyimage8
pyimage9
pyimage10
```

pero al final se abre una pantalla negra

[SEGUNDA CORRECCIÓN]

```
from Tkinter import*
def p():
     root = Tk()
     sp = Ventana(root)
     sp.config(bg="black")
     Img1=PhotoImage(file="Libre.gif")
     Img2=PhotoImage(file="Soy.gif")
     Img3=PhotoImage(file="universe.gif")
     Img4=PhotoImage(file="BBN.gif")
     Img5=PhotoImage(file="tr.gif")
     Img6=PhotoImage(file="final.gif")
     Img7=PhotoImage(file="alc.gif")
     Img8=PhotoImage(file="cer.gif")
     Img9=PhotoImage(file="at.gif")
     Img10=PhotoImage(file="bos.gif")
     Img11=PhotoImage(file="se.gif")
     #Img=PhotoImage(file=".gif")
     Imagenes=[Img1,Img2,Img3,Img4,Img5,Img7,Img8,Img9,Img10]
     def imgor():
          for imagen in Imagenes:
              imagen
              print imagen
     Imagenfin=imgor()
     lbl=Label(root,image=imgor()).place(x=00,y=00)
     root.after(6010,root.destroy())
     root.mainloop()
```

ahora si está el codigo completo

Comment: Por favor, añade el código del for loop para que podamos ver si tiene algún problema. ¿A qué te refieres con "me muestra es la posición de la lista"?

Comment: En principio necesitarás algún método de persistencia para que la información sea almacenada entre ejecuciones del script. Esto puede ser desde un simple archivo en el disco duro (incluido pickle) donde guardar el índice y en la siguiente ejecución lo recuperas, lees la imágen correpondiente, lo incrementas y lo guardas de nuevo, hasta usar bases de datos locales o remotas. No obstante, falta mucha información, como dice Álvaro, para poder darte una respuesta concreta.

Comment: ger varias cosas, en python  es esencial la identación, cuando copies código aquí debes mantenerla tal y como la tiene tu. Por otro lado, presupongo que estas usando Tkinter (deberia agregarlo como etiqueta o comentarlo). Parece que quieres crear un label con la imagen `lbl=Label(root,image=imgor()).place(x=00,y=00)` pero `imgor()` no retorna ninguna imagen, solo imprime el contenido de `Imágenes` . Por favor, agrega un [mcve]. Además, dices que quieres que cada vez que se ejecute el programa cargue una nueva imagen, para eso como te comente necesitas persistencia de datos. Aclara esto.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿`Imagenes` es una lista de instancias de `PhotoImage`?. Si quieres que se cree un solo label con una imagen diferente cada vez que inicias tu GUI no necesitas un for, necesitas obtener un índice diferente cada vez. Si quieres mostrar todas las imágenes a la vez usa un  for y crea un Label por cada imagen.  Deberias tomarte tu tiempo en explicar que es lo que quieres exactamente y en agregar un código mínimo pero completo que muestre tu problema. Es mucho más fácil obtener una respuesta adecuada si no tenemos que adivinar paso a paso lo que quieres. Saludos.

Comment: gracias FJSevilla siempre es muy acertado con las respuestas en lo posible ya que en este caso no proveí los datos correctamente ahora tengo 2 preguntas quisiera saber que datos me hicieron falta en la pregunta para poder mejorar en la formulación de preguntas y segundo cuál es la forma correcta para obtener un índice diferente cada vez

Comment: Ok, ger ahora vamos bién. Una sola duda, veo que englobas en una función el código, ¿la idea es ejecutar un script, que este  llame a la función y que se muestren las imagenes una detras de otra en orden (como una presentación)?,¿que cada vez que se llame a la función desde el script habra una ventana mostrando una imagen distinta?, ¿o que cada vez que habramos nuestro programa (ejecutemos el script) se muestre una imagen distinta? Una cosa, veo que usas .gif, Tkinter no anima los Gif, se verán estáticos :(. Se puede hacer algún arreglo pero no es todo lo bueno que debería. Saludos.

Comment: ok FJSevilla yo quiero saber si me podrías brindar una dirección de contacto como e-mail o algo así veo que sabes mucho y quisera que me pudiese comunicar continuamente

Comment: ger [so] no permite por medios propios ni promueve la comunicación privada entre usuarios.La filosofía del sitio persigue que el conocimiento generado sea público y pueda servir de ayuda a todo el mundo y no solo al que pregunta.No obstante, para poder aclarar preguntas (como en este caso) o para temas más distendidos si que se puede usar el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com). El problema es que necesitas 20 de reputación (algo podemos hacer si te interesa) para poder participar.Intenta  aclarar lo que tu programa debe hacer y te intento ayudar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

O lo que puedes hacer es ayudarte con varias estructuras de datos para que te faciliten el trabajo. Puedes asignar a cada persona su puntuación utilizando un diccionario y sucesivamente guardar todas las puntuaciones obtenidas por los participantes en un set con las cuales vas a construir otro diccionario.

En este tu value va a ser un listado de todos los participantes que obtuvieron esa puntuación que será el key del nuevo diccionario.

Al final imprimes los resultados con dos for anidados y puedes utilizar una variable para que diga el lugar del participante.

Dependiendo de la política de tu juego puede o no que haya brincos de lugares si muchos usuarios obtuvieron la misma puntuación. Mira este ejemplo para que puedas entender mejor.

Comment: podrias añadir un ejemplo para asi poder entender y comprender mejor el funcionamiento de lo que dices?